# Update python in base conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a clean Anaconda installation that, for some reason, came with Python 3.8.8, while I know the latest stable release should be 3.10.
If I run

```
conda update python
```

I'm asked if I want to install 3.8.12.

I know I can create a new environment with

```
conda create -n py310 python=3.10
```

However I'd like to "replace" the base 3.8.8 environment with a new 3.10 one.
Is it possible to update python in the base environment? If not, can I create a new environment and then replace the `base` environment with the new one?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a deliberate choice in conda, to keep on the same minor version of Python. If you would like to update to a new minor version, you can do

```sh
conda install python=3.X
```

However, Python 3.10 may not be a good choice (or even possible) in your base environment, because it is possible that not all dependencies have been built for 3.10 yet. You'll probably have better luck with Python 3.9.

Comment: I have this problem at this moment: I had python 3.7.12 in my conda base environment and trying to `conda install python=3.10`. It's taking HOURS. 24h now and counting.

Comment: Try mamba, in case this still hasn't finished solving. Lots of packages makes it hard for Conda to resolve everything. Or, what I usually do, is `rm -rf ~/anaconda3` and reinstall with mambaforge.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry much about the base environment. For any serious work, you should rather create a dedicated conda environment, because the base environment needs to contain all the dependencies of conda itself which might be in conflict with what you want to install.

In case you're working in any kind of container I would anyway strongly suggest to use a more lightweight installation method for your environment than conda.

And if you only need one environment, you also don't need the feature of the separate environments. You can for example install a plain Python 3.10 or 3.11 from python.org and simply use pip to install the packages you need.

Comment: Apparently, having base python=3.7 prevents `conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda` from working, which is the problem I'm having that led me to this SO question. So, base environment can mess things up if it's old enough. See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12166

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I can only discourage using it for project work

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
conda activate base
conda install python=3.n
```